# PHP exec(): Why can I access shared memory, but not named semaphores? (errno = 13)

Tags: php, c, ipc, shared-memory, semaphore

I'm using the php `exec()` command to run, `get_value.c`. `get_value.c` attached to shared memory reads a value and returns it to my PHP script. It worked just fine during my initial testing of attaching to shared memory.

Then when I added the semaphore**, `sem_open()` returns errno = 13.

I put a switch block on `errno` and listed out all the error cases from the `sem_open` `man` page. Error 13 is not getting trapped and it just falls through to the the default case.

What is error 13?

** I created the semaphore with permissions (0666 | O_CREAT | O_EXCL).

**EDIT:** Everything works from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP `exec("whoami");` to determine the user, it is likely `www-data`.

This will let you know the user with which apache is trying to access system resources. Then you need to enable this user to access those resources.

This user is typically located in:
`/etc/apache2/envvars`